# Action Constraint is being animated for some reason

Tags: rigging, bones, constraints, actions

Something strange is happening to my rig. I'm using Blender 2.8 and I began rigging with an Action Constraint and for some reason it's playing the Action that I made and stored. I've double checked and there are no keyframes in the timeline and yet it's still playing the Action.

Thinking it as a bug, I tried reproducing it from scratch from a new file but I can't and things seem to work perfectly fine(?). I'm even starting to think that this bug is specific to the file I'm working on and I don't want to start over again...

Here's the file focusing on a sample problem:
[what.blend](https://drive.google.com/open?id=18acJuEGP2wu-GW5m7OtgqQcz0PQOoFmf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you've pushed the action in the NLA, open the NLA window and remove the strip, your object won't be animated anymore.

Comment: You're right. I barely use the NLA and I don't even remember opening it while working... but still thank you very much!

Comment: you may have pushed it with the Push Down button? I don't know...

Comment: That actually makes sense. Guess I have to be careful on that. Thanks again.